# Installshield 2011 dynamic scanning not opening my .exe

Tags: qt, installshield

I am trying to get all possible dependencies into the executable folder of my application so I can deploy it properly.

Using Installshield 2011, I am doing a dynamic dependency scan. It is suppose to open the application for me, make me test all the features so that it captures all the dependencies, and finally add them. Unfortunately it is not even openning the application for me to start testing..

The application runs when I double click it or run it from command line normally.. I cannot figure out what is the problem.. Any idea ? Or anything else I can do to get all the libraries?

Notice: The dynamic wizard opens any other .exe files except the one I need, which was built using Qt.

Thanks.

Comment: Does the application run in a debugger, or, conversely, does it employ any anti-debugger technologies?

Comment: I think I figured out what is the problem.. But do not know how to fix it.. I think it has to do with what you re saying. I am not able to profile the application using Dependency Walker as well. Also it appears that a lot of dlls are missing. But somehow the application runs.. I have no idea why.. Do you know how can I properly get all the .dlls do I can pass my application to someone else.. Im having a lot of trouble doing so .. Is that common?

Comment: Personally I prefer not to depend on dependency scanning, and especially not dynamic dependency scanning. Instead request a list of dependencies from the developers and add them to the project by hand.